# RaveReport to PDF/A

Tags: delphi, rave-reports, pdfa

Is there a possibility to export RaveReports to PDF/A?
We use RaveReport with TurboDelphi and currenty RaveReport 7.0.5.
It should be with few changes at the report itself because we have hundreds of reports in use right now.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can access the RaveReport pages as a list of `TMetaFile` instances.

Then you can use our Open Source [SynPDF library to render them as PDF/A](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/02/08/Synopse-PDF-Engine-1.12). Since the library is fully vectorial, it will export metafiles as vectors, not as bitmaps. This will create smaller files if the metafiles are big and result in better preview and print quality.  You can also use the enhanced security options of the library.

Comment: i was looking, before i posted here, at your solution and was was already looking for possibilities to generate a meta file but since i only found a guide about it with fast report i hoped somebody already did the legwork for me. the support for rave report is non existing...if nobody will post a guide i will of course mark your answer as resolver thank you